# How To Add Props to a Navbar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Navbar that contains a close button. The Navbar is a separate component, but is being brought into my AppLayout.js file. Inside my AppLayout I manage the state of the Navbar, which currently by default is set to false, and if it's false, it will not appear and a button prompting the user to open the Navbar will appear instead.

Now the problem is, inside my Navbar I have another button which fires an onClick=setShowNav(false) in order to close the Navbar, BUT the problem is that all my state for the Navbar is managed inside AppLayout, so I guess I have to pass in some prop to the Navbar component in order to get the close button to work.

I'm unsure what's the correct syntax/way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the AppLayout file create a function :

```
const closeNavbarHandler = () =>{
 setShowNav(false)
}
```

Now pass down this function as a prop to navbar component :

```
<Navbar onClose={closeNavbarHandler } />
```

Inside the Navbar component file, create a function :

```
const closeNavbar = () =>{
props.onClose();
}
```

and pass this function as onClick to the button which will close the navbar

```
<button onClick={closeNavbar} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably there are more orthodox ways to do it (like using useContext or Redux), but you can lift up the state to the parent and pass state and setState as props to the child.